# Hide feature image when is not populated

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a customized a comercial theme with featured images capabilities.
When I have a post with featured image everything is ok, but when the post hasn't a featured image the template charge an empty div;

[image: with/without featured image]

how I can solve this issue?

**My code**

[image: code used]

Comment: Please post you code here, not on other sites.

Comment: You _can_ post your code here without putting it in an image, much easier for us to look into your code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `<div class="single-post-thumb" >` is the one with the border etc.

Change your code to this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) {
  echo '<div class="single-post-thumb" >';

  tie_thumb( '', $width, $height );

  if ( get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id( ) )->post_excerpt ) {
    echo '<div class="post_thumbnail-caption">' . get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id( ) )->post_excerpt . '</div>';
```

This will cause the `<div class="single-post-thumb" >` to only show up when the post has a post thumbnail.

*I don't know what `tie_thumb( )` does but seeing the code I expect it to show the thumbnail.*